# Dealing with Pointers in C++

Tags: c++

In the following code, I am having trouble figuring out **how to make b point to c so that if you change the value pointed to by b, c is changed (but not a)**. I tried `int *b = &c;`. So my question ultimately is: **How do you point to a value that is pointing to another, without changing the value of the former?**

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
int a = 8;
int c = 12;
//std::cout<< a<< std::endl;
std::cout << &a << std::endl;

int *b = &a;

std::cout << *b << std::endl;
std::cout << b << std::endl;
std::cout << b+1 << std::endl;

a = 6;

std::cout << *b << std::endl;

b = &c; // just edited this now it works. 

//std::cout << c << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want, and the code you've provided isn't helpful.

Comment: *"how to make b point to c so that if you change the value pointed to by b, c is changed (but not a)"* You can't. That's not how pointers work. That is literally the opposite of how they should work.

Comment: @grillo Would it be enough to simply make assignment b = &c;?

Comment: @Cyber Sounds like exactly how they work. :S

Comment: @JosephMansfield "How do you point to a value that is pointing to another, without changing the value of the former?" makes it sound like he's chaining pointers and trying to chance something without affecting everything.

Comment: This is a weird question.  You knew how to do b = &a, but not how to do b = &c?  Strange...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the address of `c` and assign it to `b`:

```
b = &c;
```

Now if you dereference `b`, with `*b`, you get the object denoted by `c`. If you modify this object in anyway, it will not affect the value of `a`.

Comment: @grillo What error do you get? You will get an error if you do `int b = &c;`, but not `b = &c;`.

Comment: You get that error because you try to redeclare `b` not because you cannot assing &c to it.